# How enable ActiveMQ persistence?

Tags: activemq

I want save not consumed messages after amq or machine restart.
Is this doc actual for ActiveMQ 5.12.1 Release?
I try use example from docs and get error:

> ERROR | Failed to load: class path resource [activemq.xml], reason:
>   Line 86 in XML document from class path resource [activemq.xml] is
>   invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
>   lineNumber: 86; columnNumber: 90; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid
>   content was found starting with element 'kahaPersistenceAdapter'. One
>   of '{"http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":jdbcPersistenceAdapter,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":journalPersistenceAdapter,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":kahaDB,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":levelDB,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":mKahaDB,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":memoryPersistenceAdapter,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":replicatedLevelDB,
>   WC[##other:"http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"]}' is expected.

This error occurs with almost default config: https://yadi.sk/d/e8tWyIzyk9piV

Well, i replace kahaPersistenceAdapter to kahaDB and restart. And get error:

> Attribute 'maxDataFileLength' is not allowed to appear in element
>   'kahaDB'.

I replace this attribute and ActiveMQ started. I send message to queue, restard amq and my not consumed message gone. What i do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you just must send special header with message.

```
$amq_headers['persistent'] = "true";
```

And your message persisted.